# c# form. problemas para guardar la suma de datos dentro de un foreach

Tags: c#

espero no molestarlos con esta pregunta que quizas ya ya hayan respondido un sin fin de veces. pero la verdad es que he visto un sin fin de posible soluciones que a otros si le funcionaron pero a mi no.

```
                {foreach (DataRow productRow in tableProduct.Select())
                {
                                 
                    dgvTableSales.Rows[index].Cells["amount"].Value = txtQuantityToSell.Text;
                    dgvTableSales.Rows[index].Cells["idProduct"].Value =productRow["IDPRODUCTO"];
                    dgvTableSales.Rows[index].Cells["codeProduct"].Value = productRow["CODIGO"];
                    dgvTableSales.Rows[index].Cells["product"].Value = productRow["PRODUCTO"];
                    dgvTableSales.Rows[index].Cells["salePrice"].Value = productRow["PRECIO_VENTA"];
                    dgvTableSales.Rows[index].Cells["stock"].Value = productRow["STOCK"];

                    //declaramos las variables para buscar el 
                    amount = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantityToSell.Text);
                    salePrice = Convert.ToDouble(dgvTableSales.Rows[index].Cells["salePrice"].Value);
                    //ahora llenamos el campo total de la tabla.
                    //para eso usaremos la formula (cantidad * precio)
                    total = (amount * salePrice);
                    //luego de calcular el total este se agrega a la tabla
                    dgvTableSales.Rows[index].Cells["total"].Value = total;

                    //double totalPay = total;
                    var result = Convert.ToDouble( tableProduct.Compute("Sum(PRECIO_VENTA)*"+ amount + "", ""));

                    fullPayment = result;                     

                }//fin foreach
                FullPayment(fullPayment);
```

en este metodo lleno mi datagrid. lo que quiero es poder almacenar en una variable o array el total de todos los productos que compro el cliente. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualmente solo logro capturar el primer elemente o producto que se agrega ya que en la siguiente iteracion del foreach los datos que tengo en mi total se borran.

```
 private void FullPayment(double pay)


    {
        double payTotal = 0.0;

        payTotal = payTotal + pay;
        txtTotalToPay.Text = "RD$  " + payTotal;
    }
```

este ultimo metodo es donde intento guardar el resultado de todo los totales
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He puesto una posible solución, me avisas si te funciona :)

Answer (score 0):

Una forma es, dentro del foreach utilizar la celda e ir acumulando el valor para lueho mostrarlo:

```
foreach(DataGridView a in tabla.Selet(){
  int valor = 0;
  if( a.Cells('total').Value != null){
    valor += (Int32)a.Cells('total').Value;
  }
  MessageBox.Show(valor.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gracias a todos por tomarse su tiempo. ya di con el problema y dejo la solucion por si a alguien mas le pasa.

```
private void CalcularTotal()
    {
        double TOTAL = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvTableSales.Rows)
        {
            double importe = double.Parse(dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            TOTAL += importe;
        }
        txtTotalToPay.Text = "RD$  " + TOTAL; }
```

double importe guarda el valor de la celda numero 5 en mi casi es la fila total.
ya luego de eso es solo llamar al metodo donde agregas  y eliminas filas. y listo. :)

Comment: Y en que se diferencia esto de la respuesta que te dieron?

Comment: y para el caso, no uses double para acumular importes, usa decimal...